# Multiple identical sendMessage calls hangs handler

Tags: android

I made a misprint in my code and found interesting behavior. When you send several identical Messages with sendMessage, a handler stops to receive messages. Example:

```
    HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("ServiceStartArguments", android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
    thread.start();

    // Get the HandlerThread's Looper and use it for our Handler
    mServiceLooper = thread.getLooper();
    mServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler(mServiceLooper);

    Message msg = mServiceHandler.obtainMessage();
    msg.what = action;
    mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg);

    mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg);
```

As you can see I called twice `mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg)`. After the second call `mServiceHandler` stopped to receive any further messages at all.

Can someone explain such behavior? I didn't find anything related in docs.

Code is tested with Android 4.4.2 in emulator.

Comment: what does your logcat show?

Comment: Nothing specific. No exceptions. No errors. I log my event to logcat and didn't see anything specific from OS.

Only: 
12-28 23:45:24.035    6166-6179/com.trukom.gpstracking.test D/dalvikvm﹕ JIT unchain all for threadid=1

Comment: @sasha_trn Now I am facing the same problem.Did you got any answer for your question?

Comment: I removed second call of sendMessage of the same message. Check that you always send new instance of Message, that you don't use the same instance of Message twice.